# "403 - usageLimits" on youtube api

Tags: android, api, youtube

I have this JSON response from my call from my android App to YouTube API:

```
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
    "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."
}
```

My [url](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&fields=items(id%2FvideoId%2Csnippet%2Ftitle%2Csnippet%2Fdescription%2Csnippet%2Fthumbnails%2Fdefault%2Furl)&type=video&key=***) is correct (acoording to [youTube search list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list))

I read somewhere that I should send a browser-key and NO an android-key, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The error seems clear to me:

**Your URL is good, but you just exceeded your quota on Youtube API.**

> There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions.

I believe this is still true:

> Version 3 of the YouTube Data API has concrete quota numbers listed in the Google API Console where you register for your API Key. You can use 30,000 units/second/user and 50,000,000 per day.

Comment: @StefanMaimon Have you looked at your Developers Console and its quotas? Did that helped?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. For some reason, even one search at the beginning of a day gives me the same error. Is it possible that there's another issue? And do you possibly know how much one youtube point (cost) is worth in real money?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is explained in the response you got:

> Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.

Your request was blocked because it came from an IP address that didn't match the IP restrictions for that key. I don't know if you're using a browser or server key. I created a server key and I use it to test both with my browser as well as my server. After creating the server key check the 'allowed IPs' option on the API Access tab and make sure its blank to allow for all IPs that provide a valid key. Likewise, if you're using a browser key check the 'allowed referrers' and make sure its blank: https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect

Answer (score 0):

1. You may remove domain restrictions from "Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites)", if you have added one. Once its working you can add DOMAIN name restriction later.
   Also Domain ownership validation process is needed, if Domain restrictions are added.
2. generate and use "browser" type key, if integrating to a website/ webpage.

thanks.