# YouTube api (Data) trying to run sample code for search

Tags: java, youtube-api

I have set up my API key, my client id, and my client secret, but when I run the sample code it gets to `SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();` and then throws a `GoogleJsonResponseException` saying `There was a service error 400 : Bad Request`.

Is there something else I need to change in the sample code?

[Here](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/Search.java) is a link to the sample code.

Here is the stacktrace.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Bad Request",
    "reason" : "keyInvalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Bad Request"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data.Search.main(Search.java:112)
There was a service error: 400 : Bad Request
```

Comment: It doesn't hurt to post the stack trace associated with the `GoogleJsonResponseException` you claim to be getting. It may even help.

Comment: Add this, so you can see more details when the Exception is thrown. e.printStackTrace(); I would double-check the API key.

Comment: I ran the stack trace and it appears that my API key is invalid, but I am not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was actually just that I had a space at the end of my API key, which made the key invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The usageLimits suggest that you already use all your quota.

More information can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081358/12511801) or search for `usagelimits youtube api`.

I do remember read in the documentation about this error.

You can try also get another API key and try again.

Comment: I am not sure how I could have used all of my quota when this is my first time using it.

Comment: @Void have you checked if you have quota? also, if this problem remains might be possible that your client ID/secret has some problems, if so (*or this problem continues with new credentials*), you best choice is report this issue to [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).